# get 403 with axios but work with Postman. how I can convert postman request to NodeJS script

Tags: node.js, axios

I want to request quillbot rest api to paraphraser some sentences
my NodeJS script get 403 with axios but manual request with Postman work correctly.
how I can convert postman request to NodeJS script?
i just copy script from postman code section but script get 403 error
please help me

Using axios request get 403 forbidden but [postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXbD1.jpg) works

```
async function Paraphraser(sentence) {
  var axios = require('axios');

  var config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://rest.quillbot.com/api/paraphraser/single-paraphrase/10?text=An%20animal%20rehabilitation%20center%20in%20western%20Pennsylvania%20has%20released%20the%20findings%20of%20a%20DNA%20test%20for%20a%20rescued%20critter%20brought%20in%20to%20the%20center%20last%20month.&strength=10&autoflip=false&wikify=false&fthresh=-1&inputLang=en&quoteIndex=-1',
    headers: {
      authority: 'rest.quillbot.com',
      'sec-ch-ua':
        ' Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google Chrome";v="98"',
      accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      useridtoken:
        'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjI3ZGRlMTAyMDAyMGI3OGZiODc2ZDdiMjVlZDhmMGE5Y2UwNmRiNGQiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.Ylxt5l_Wx3SZzGy4t8zli8sc_YxC228JfsLB2_LQeduJeI6kW3V7brX8RU_SctcbmjqnJjOpEaCMGQl0sY9-_JtPVIBY3Lk5Bb9sDIzJbUWWr4r5sJ64--slSO1L3jzkZ2jJqSp07qc1fxwLWaVN9cHbtbucdtUQf4pJfPDIIAhHsxnRJEiVluLlQoMq9-eBcEqze2CGSjqmbNbScvBT4v8AEptH6UONlptTnh1m-ht1Eiob32TBg3FGtePqPt1J4yj4NNDlHYOHujD__Fg5VnY3MkZNc4_pcs2nu8kslYse-XqxQ46oYcqcL-HvvS08rWc6N6YbPBum6FZ0JoBoow',
      'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
      'sec-ch-ua-platform': 'Windows',
      origin: 'https://quillbot.com',
      'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
      'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
      'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
      referer: 'https://quillbot.com/',
      'accept-language':
        'en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8,ms;q=0.7,ru;q=0.6,de;q=0.5,ar;q=0.4',
      cookie:
        '_gcl_au=1.1.238290589.1644093509; user_status=not registered; _fbp=fb.1.1644093511879.1194997150; __stripe_mid=74321944-72bf-4aa9-914a-08e7f25188291efdb2; _gid=GA1.2.1063220069.1645089761; _clck=bdtktc|1|ez2|0; connect.sid=s%3A2s-idf5SfypB5a3n-Yzi-CciFn-r4rrs.RRLddIdW%2FvinkfnBuEpxXAeKe7sFRQROx4haGHacK5c; qdid=7f709938-003e-4ba8-8874-9053f77c07b2; _gat=1; _uetsid=28ab11d08fd311ecbd1b9f76c5fdcb6c; _uetvid=93ea401086c311ec93a939481c0c6bc0; __insp_wid=379258038; __insp_slim=1645101826748; __insp_nv=true; __insp_targlpt=UGFyYXBocmFzaW5nIFRvb2wgfCBRdWlsbEJvdCBBSQ%3D%3D; __insp_targlpu=aHR0cHM6Ly9xdWlsbGJvdC5jb20v; __insp_norec_sess=true; _clsk=115tq3s|1645101829258|2|0|a.clarity.ms/collect; _ga_KQNKKHJ2B0=GS1.1.1645101823.15.1.1645101839.0; _ga=GA1.1.974758787.1644093508; amp_6e403e=cmUrlO20DOtc6EUZ6FFZI-.a2VsZWlzLmFuZHJlLjIwMjBAZ21haWwuY29t..1fs3rbdgr.1fs3rcea5.7r.t.8o; connect.sid=s%3A2s-idf5SfypB5a3n-Yzi-CciFn-r4rrs.RRLddIdW%2FvinkfnBuEpxXAeKe7sFRQROx4haGHacK5c',
      'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.28.1',
      'Postman-Token': '9dfb9a2a-d8ea-458e-8e47-272f576ea661',
      Host: 'rest.quillbot.com',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
      Connection: 'keep-alive',
    },
  };

  axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate code snippets from PostMan as described here

https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/

You can generate NodeJS, Axios as well from there.

Comment: thanks but I also use postman Code snippet. but with generate code i get 403 erorr